# Combining multiple small T-SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get data from a table that is identified by ID's from other tables; they all feed into each other. For example:

```
Get tblA.ID
Using tblA.ID, get tblB.ID
Using tblB.ID, get tblC.ID
Using tblC.ID, get tblD.Username
```

So I would begin with:

```
SELECT [ID]
FROM tblA
WHERE [Name] = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

But how would I continue the trail?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a `JOIN`. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Username 
FROM tblD 
JOIN tblC ON tblC.ID = tblD.ID
JOIN tblB ON tblB.ID = tblC.ID
JOIN tblA ON tblA.ID = tblB.ID
```

Presumably you would use other columns joining each of the tables together, but this follows your example as closely as possible.